# Why php json_decode not working

Tags: php, json

```
$city_names=json_decode('{"CityList":[{"Id":"1","Name":"Москва","Alias":"msk","Phone":null},{"Id":"2","Name":"Санкт-Петербург","Alias":"spb","Phone":null},{"Id":"4","Name":"Екатеринбург","Alias":"ekb","Phone":null},{"Id":"5","Name":"Новосибирск","Alias":"nsk","Phone":null},{"Id":"6","Name":"Пермь","Alias":"perm","Phone":null},{"Id":"7","Name":"Нижний Новгород","Alias":"nn","Phone":null},{"Id":"8","Name":"Казань","Alias":"kazan","Phone":null},{"Id":"9","Name":"Самара","Alias":"samara","Phone":null},{"Id":"11","Name":"Московская область","Alias":"mo","Phone":null},{"Id":"13","Name":"Уфа","Alias":"ufa","Phone":null},{"Id":"15","Name":"Краснодар","Alias":"krd","Phone":null},{"Id":"17","Name":"Ростов-на-Дону","Alias":"rnd","Phone":null},{"Id":"19","Name":"Челябинск","Alias":"chlb","Phone":null},{"Id":"21","Name":"Воронеж","Alias":"vrn","Phone":null},{"Id":"23","Name":"Ижевск","Alias":"izh","Phone":null}]}',true);

print_r($city_names);
```

I receive empty.

Comment: It is working fine. Try this https://eval.in/795253

Comment: Try setting your script to utf8: **mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');**

Comment: it works fine please check again

Comment: working fine:- https://eval.in/795257

Comment: You aren't getting "empty", you're probably getting `FALSE`. What does `json_last_error_msg()` print?

Comment: Try to remove Russian characters, just to know if it encoding issue.  {"CityList":[{"id":test}]}

Comment: ini_set("display_errors", "1");  ... add this in top of file in php code ...

Comment: my encoding is windows-1251. I used iconv and it is working. Thanks Remco K.

Answer (score 1):

Try using json_last_error() to get the error.

like this.

```
$json[] = "{'json': 'MyJson'}";

foreach ($json as $string) {
    echo 'Decoding: ' . $string;
    json_decode($string);

    switch (json_last_error()) {
        case JSON_ERROR_NONE:
            echo ' - No errors';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_DEPTH:
            echo ' - Maximum stack depth exceeded';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH:
            echo ' - Underflow or the modes mismatch';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR:
            echo ' - Unexpected control character found';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX:
            echo ' - Syntax error, malformed JSON';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_UTF8:
            echo ' - Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded';
        break;
        default:
            echo ' - Unknown error';
        break;
    }

    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this solutions:

```
$json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';

var_dump(json_decode($json));
var_dump(json_decode($json, true));

?>
```